# Erro ao Conectar em Impressora Bluetooth Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1, silverlight

Ao tentar conectar na Impressora Bluetooth dá o Seguinte erro. "No more data is available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070103)".

Esse erro só deu apartir do Visual Studio 2013, no Visual Studio 2012 Funcionava normal.
Meu Código.

```
            PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "BlueTooth Printer";
            var pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

            if (pairedDevices.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No paired devices were found.");
            }
            else
            {
                PeerInformation selectedDevice = pairedDevices[0];
                StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();

                await socket.ConnectAsync(selectedDevice.HostName, "1");
                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.AsBuffer(buffer));
                socket.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: [Esse tópico](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/7da5590e-7423-48a9-8195-2a48229ee482/exception-wp81-bluetooth-connectivity-using-rfcomm-api?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK) no msdn ajuda em algo?

Comment: @renan valeu cara funcionou, agora adiciona como resposta para eu lhe dar os pontos.

Comment: Não esquenta com isso cara, o importante é ter ajudado. Posta como resposta a sua solução e se tiver encontrado o motivo dessa exceção ser lançada no VS2013 e não no VS2012, inclua também. **:)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DeviceInformationCollection DeviceInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
var numDevices = DeviceInfoCollection.Count();

if (numDevices == 0)
{
   MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("No paired devices found", "Title");
   await md.ShowAsync();
   return;
}

DeviceInformation DeviceInfo = DeviceInfoCollection[0];

StreamSocket socket = null;
try
{
   var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync( DeviceInfo.Id);

   socket = new StreamSocket();

// Note: If either parameter is null or empty, the call will throw an exception
await socket.ConnectAsync(service.ConnectionHostName, service.ConnectionServiceName, service.ProtectionLevel);


// If the connection was successful, the RemoteAddress field will be populated
MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(String.Format("Connected to {0}!", socket.Information.RemoteAddress.DisplayName), "Title");
await md.ShowAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  socket.Dispose();
  socket = null;
}
```